# Not able to make controls Visible and hidden in a window in WPF with viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, visibility

I implemented a textbox and it have to become visible when a checkbox is'nt checked and vica versa. 
Here is my view:

```
 <TextBox Visibility="{Binding VisiMaxTime}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,36,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=MaxTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MaxTimeIsChecked}" Content="Geen" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,39,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

And this is my viewmodel:

```
public bool MaxTimeIsChecked
        {
            get { return maxTimeIsChecked; }
            set
            {
                maxTimeIsChecked = value;
                if (maxTimeIsChecked == true)
                {
                    VisiMaxTime = Visibility.Hidden;
                    this.Examination.MaxTime = 0;
                }

                else
                VisiMaxTime = Visibility.Visible;
                OnPropertyChanged("MaxTimeIsChecked");
            }
        }



private Visibility visiMaxTime;
        public Visibility VisiMaxTime
        {
            get { return visiMaxTime; }
            set
            {
                visiMaxTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("VisiMaxTime");
            }
        }
```

So i think this is good, this works in usercontrols but now i am working in a window. If i set a breakpoint in the setters of Visibility, it works fine, but the textbox just does'nt become visible? Does somebody know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you raising `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes, i edited it, with the visibility property..

Comment: If the code works in a UserControl it should work in a Window without any changes. I can't see anything wrong the code. Did you copy and paste the actual code into this question? Try setting a break point in you OnPropertyChanged method to ensure the property changes are being raised as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the visiblity of the textbox depends on Checkbox, why not bind to that directly?

```
 <TextBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1,Path=IsChecked,Converter=BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
```

you will need to use BooleanToVisibilityConverter to convert Bool to Visiblity

Comment: He gives an error if i put that in it:
'Set property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Converter' threw an exception.' Line number '13' and line position '260'.
I think it is with Converter:
I have this in window props: xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ToetsBeheerTweedeZit.Converters"
 <Window.Resources>
        <converters:BooleanToHiddenVisibility x:Key="boolToVis2"/>
    </Window.Resources>

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you need two-way binding:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MaxTimeIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" … />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your TextBox's DataContext correct?

I noticed that your `MaxTime` property is defined set in your ViewModel as `ExaminationTime.MaxTime`, while your TextBox.Text binding is bound to `MaxTime`. Is your TextBox's DataContext your ViewModel, or your ExaminationTime?

Comment: Yes, the textbox is binded to the Maxtime property in the viewmodel, and there i set the maxtime of my examination object..

Comment: @Ruben The code you posted in your question works fine. Is it the actual code that produces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the VisiMaxTime property doesn't update the MaxTimeIsChecked property

```
private Visibility visiMaxTime;         
public Visibility VisiMaxTime         
{             
           get { return visiMaxTime; }             
           set             
           {   
                if (visiMaxTime == value)
                    return;           
                visiMaxTime = value;                 
                OnPropertyChanged("VisiMaxTime");   
                MaxTimeIsChecked = VisiMaxTime == Visibility.Visible;          
            }        
 }
```

That being said, you could just bind to the MaxTimeIsChecked property and use a BooleanToVisibilityConverter